# Tesseract installed via home-brew, Anaconda says no module 'pytesseract?

Tags: python, anaconda, tesseract, python-tesseract

Sorry, complete newbie question here.....I installed tesseract, tesseract-lang both via homebrew, also via the terminal (using conda install https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tesseract ). In the terminal it looks like it is installed as I get this message when I try to reinstall it;

```
 ~ % conda install -c conda-forge tesseract
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
```

## All requested packages already installed.

However, when I run this code;

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract 
import numpy as np

filename = 'example_image_01.png'
img1 = np.array(Image.open(filename))
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img1)

print(text)

Anaconda returns;
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytesseract'
```

I have also tried it with just tesseract but to no avail.

Anyone have any suggestions given I am relatively inexperienced as I am still learning python.

Thanks,
Trevor

Answer (score 0):

The packages [`tesseract`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tesseract) and [`pytesseract`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pytesseract) are distinct. The latter is what provides Python bindings for interacting with the former. That is, you need to install both packages to use the latter:

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge pytesseract tesseract
```

Technically, if one already has `tesseract` installed on the system-level, then it should not need to be separately installed in the Conda environment. However, some may regard it as better practice to include everything needed to replicate a project in the Conda environment.

Comment: Thanks for coming back on this. When I use this command (thank you for mentioning the better practice) in the terminal it returns this;

Comment: % conda install -c conda-forge pytesseract tesseract
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

Comment: I can see it in the terminal but not in VSCode or Spyder even after this conda install command. Also, thank you for helping @Merv I am very grateful.

Comment: @T-RevLey make sure you are executing the Python code in the Anaconda environment.

Comment: Thanks, @Merv took a bit of time but figured out what you meant (that's because I'm a complete novice) but I got it when I moved from where it was installed into the right directory. Thank you for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: @T-RevLey it's not about directories - it's about [activating the Conda environment](https://conda.io/projects/continuumio-conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment). I'd recommend working through Conda documentation.

Comment: Ah got it. Working through environments now, thank you again for all the assistance